# R - how to save attributes with various data type in one XML node?

Tags: r, xml

I have 2 values that I would like to save as a different attributes in the same XML node:

```
> str(TestDate)
 Date[1:1], format: "2017-12-18"
```

and

```
> str(TestCar)
 chr "HONDA"
```

As you can see one value is a date and another one is a character.
I would like to create an XML node like this:

```
<TestXML Date="2017-12-18" Car="HONDA"/>
```

I use `newXMLNode` function from the `XML` package:

```
newXMLNode("TestXML", attrs=c(Date=TestDate, Car=TestCar))
```

and I get:

```
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.Date(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

If I change order of the attributes:

```
   newXMLNode("TestXML",attrs=c(Car=TestCar, Date=TestDate))
```

I get:

```
<TestXML Car="HONDA" Date="17518"/>
```

It seems that data type of the first attribute is replicated for every attribute in the node. Do anyone knows how to save attributes that have various data type in one XML node? (It doesn't necessary need to be the XML package)

Comment: Use list, not a vector. Try `newXMLNode("TestXML", attrs=list(Date=TestDate, Car=TestCar))`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, but it doesn't work with list either